# How to set query timeout in Spring Boot using Mysql as Databse?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring boot with Mysql. I have implemented Datasource and defined properties in application.xml file.

I have a long running query:

`@Query(value - "select sleep(10)", nativeQuery=true)`
`public void test();`

in JPA repository methods.

I want to implement query timeout here. I tried using @Transactional(timeout = <>) but I do not want to use that as I will have to do this for all DB methods. I want a global solution.

I also tried setting javax.persistance.query.timeout but I think mysql does not support the same. Any suggesstions on how to implement query timeout with mysql and spring boot?

Comment: javax.persistance.query.timeout should work. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Because I have set the property in my application.properties file "spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistance.query.timeout=1000" but yet the query runs for entire 10 seconds without breaking. @SimonMartinelli

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [global property](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time), but can also specify that per session or query: [Query](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/#:%7E:text=The%20statement%20timeouts%20work%20by,larger%20transaction%20or%20connection%20contexts.)